# How to attach two devices to docker using docker run --devices?

Tags: docker, docker-run

I need to attach `/dev/video0` and `/dev/ttyUSB0` to container.

Both `docker run --device=/dev/video0 (...)` and `docker run --device=/dev/ttyUSB0 (...)`
work but how to attach them both at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `--device` flag multiple times.

```
docker run --device=/dev/video0 --device=/dev/ttyUSB0 (...)
```